# Why are so many users deleting/having their accounts deleted?

Tags: discussion

In the past week or so, I've seen reputation changes on my profile from three or four different user deletions.  Previously, I'd only ever seen one user be deleted.  Why so many removals?  Is it because of the new [CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes?cb=1)?

Comment: It's because SE has mishandled [a very complex situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/332043). The CoC is only a small part of it - there's a lot of both recent issues and old issues that lay as the foundation for the problem. There's basically enough, different reasons for everyone to have a valid reason to leave.

Comment: SE created an issue because they valued their corporate SJW stance more than they valued the community.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

People leave all the time, but yeah, it's a bit more now.  No accounts on Writing have been deleted by anyone but their owners, as far as I know (aside from outright spammers), not in the last couple of months anyway.

The system automatically changes rep to account for that person's up or down votes.  If the person was very active, then the votes stay, but I'm not sure of the algorithms used for that.

Note that deletion of an account is not the same as suspension.  When an account is suspended, the account rep goes to 1, but there is no change in the up or down votes they've previously made.  When the suspension period is over, the rep goes back to its previous state.

Answer (score 15):

Speaking as a person whose account here has only three hours left before the scheduled (I requested it) deletion kicks in, allow my to answer:  I do not recognize this or any other forum's right to compel me to use certain speech.  Not to re-litigate the whole thing here -- I am just answering the question with a data point.

The Writing SE has always been good to me, but it's a system-wide CoC.

Take care, y'all.